# Need help in executing cpp code which will include opencv libraries

Tags: php, c++, opencv

I will be creating a cpp file, which I will execute in php code using `exec()` function, that cpp file will include OpenCV libraries. So how to achieve that? Do i have to set environment variables for OpenCV? a little help please?

Comment: Do you have it running without php? At which point do you get stuck?

Comment: i havent done that, it seems i need to setup system variables. Which i dont know how to do. There are references which includes, using visual studio, cmake, and lots of other. Does cmake helps in setting up environment variables for opencv ?

Comment: So you need help setting up openCV with visual studio. I've had success with both their recommended install method http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html as well as by simply installing this nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCV/

Comment: i want to avoid so many applications, will it be easier in fedora or ubuntu?? just a question. But thanks a lot for this info..

Comment: well i have added path for open cv, so maybe now i will try and run a php code with simple cpp code with opencv libraries. Thanks a lot man.. how to mark a comment as a solution??